# Android NFC always calling onCreate when app is open

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, oncreate, activity-lifecycle

I made app that detects nfc tag. All work fine when my **app is closed** and each time I start my app by touching nfc tag to my phone.

```
08-27 16:02:12.121  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate
08-27 16:02:12.121  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
08-27 16:02:14.556  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onPause
08-27 16:02:14.571  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onNewIntent
08-27 16:02:14.576  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
08-27 16:02:20.216  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onPause
08-27 16:02:20.221  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onNewIntent
08-27 16:02:20.226  16692-16692/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
```

but when my **app is opened** (by touching app icon from menu) and when I  touch nfc tag to my phone `onCreate` method is called each time I touch nfc tag to phone. Here's my log

```
08-27 16:10:41.316  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate
08-27 16:10:41.316  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
08-27 16:10:45.581  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onPause
08-27 16:10:45.631  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate
08-27 16:10:45.631  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
08-27 16:10:47.881  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onPause
08-27 16:10:47.906  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onNewIntent
08-27 16:10:47.906  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
08-27 16:10:50.076  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onPause
08-27 16:10:50.121  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate
08-27 16:10:50.121  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
08-27 16:10:57.216  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onPause
08-27 16:10:57.236  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onNewIntent
08-27 16:10:57.236  24218-24218/v2.nfc.android.com.nfcv2 D/MainActivity﹕ onResume
```

I don't have any ideas why this is happening.

Here's my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here's my full activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private NfcAdapter adapter;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        t.setText(Math.random()+"");

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if((NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction()))){
            enableForegroundDispatch();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    private void enableForegroundDispatch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);

        try {
            intentFilter.addDataType("*/*");
        } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (adapter != null){
            adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[]{intentFilter}, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if (isNfcIntent(intent)) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent");
    }

    private boolean isNfcIntent(Intent intent){
        return intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your NFC detection Activity the same as your Launcher Activity? If so, that's why.

Comment: Well, yes NFC detection Activity the same as Launcher Activity. So I need to create second activity and add `intent filter` to it?

Comment: You don't *need* to. You can choose to if you want. Your question seemed to be: why is create being called multiple times when my App is open? The answer is that you have multiple intents pointing to the same activity. The intent used for NFC is different from the intent used to launch the App, so onCreate() is called for each different intent.

Comment: Ok, but how to fix it? When app is open`onCreate` being called each time my app detects nfc tag. So what changes I should do in my androidmanifest file?

Comment: You haven't really described *what* the issue is - you've simply stated that onCreate() is called multiple times. Why is that a problem? If you want to keep the same Activity and differentiate the launches, you should be able to do that in onCreate() using the result from `getIntent()`

Comment: Well I dont need to call `onCreate()`  method each time when my nfc tag touches device. As you can see from the first log (when my app is not running and is triggered by nfc tag) everything works fine (when nfc tag is discovered) `onCreate()` -> `onResume() ` is called (when again nfc tag is discovered) `onPause()` -> `onNewIntent()` -> `onResume()` method is called. But when my app is running (by opened manually from menu and before any nfc tag is discovered) and nfc tag is discovered activity calls `onCreate()` to often (see my post)